# Do you recommend Sql Server for storing and indexing files (pdf, office, etc)?

Tags: sql-server, lucene, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lucene.Net and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059/lucene-net-and-sql-server)

I need to storage and index files, like PDF and office files. Currently I'm using Sql Server 2k8 to perform this task using the Full text search with IFilters. My question is: Is this the "best" way? Should I switch, for instance, to Lucene for indexing?

Comment: Dupe, check on zihotki's links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not new. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059/lucenenet-and-sql-server) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120965/which-search-technology-to-use-with-aspnet) threads. And I recommend to use Lucene from my experience. It's a bit harder to set up it but it works very good.
Also you may have a look at [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/). It looks very good and has positive replies.