# Which are the best alternatives to Lucene?

Tags: lucene, search-engine

It may run on Unix and it will be used for email searching (Dovecot, Postfix and maildir).

Lucene is not a problem, I'm just analyzing some alternatives.

Comment: Do you want to quantify why you don't like Lucene, what issues you have with it or what needs it doesn't meet for you?

Comment: Your questions needs more content, if nothing else reiterate what the question is and why Lucene can't be used.

Comment: There is a good discussion on [slashdot](http://ask.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=07/10/01/1959239).

Comment: Platform, language etc would also help narrowing down the options.

Comment: So, to sum it up, the question really doesn't say it all.

Comment: I need to study alternatives. Im doing a State of the art on indexing and i needed some feedback.

Comment: So edit your question and provide more useful information. What performance measures are the most important to you. Explain why Lucene is not the besta naswer for you. Explain exactly what criteria matter the most for you.

Comment: [clucene](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene/) is lucene in C++

Answer (score 7):

For simple things native full-text search of your RDBMS.

- [Full text search in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/textsearch.html)
- [FTS2 in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=FtsTwo)
- [Full text search in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)
- [Oracle Text in Oracle DB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/content.htm#sthref2643)
- [Full text search in Microsoft SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

would need to know what problems you're having with Lucene, but [Xapian](http://xapian.org) is worth a look.

Comment: Im not having any kind of problems, im just wondering what the alternatives were.

Answer (score 3):

The ones I can come up with now is native DBMS-full-text-indexing (MSSQL, MySQL both has implementations for it) aswell as Sphinx http://www.sphinxsearch.com/about.html

The advantage with Sphinx is easier integration with MySQL and PostgreSQL, however Lucene is more feature-rich.

Answer (score 2):

[Minion](http://minion.java.net/) from Oracle Labs is a very interesting alternative to Lucene and Xapian.

Among other interesting features, it supports search results clustering.

Comment: link is gone, there is https://github.com/SunLabsAST/Minion

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative indexers are mentioned here:

> [Which search technology to use with ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120965/which-search-technology-to-use-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you consider Solr an alternative, since it's built on top of lucene.

But others are:

- Sphinx
- IndexTank
- RDBM full-text indexes (MySql, Oracle, Postgre, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Managing Gigabytes for Java(mg4j)](http://mg4j.di.unimi.it/) for its compression performance. Please see also the description of my own question: [mg4j vs. apache lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028314/mg4j-vs-apache-lucene)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the search-index module for node (https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index). Its like a simplified, leaner lucene for Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

There is now also [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). AFAIK Stackexchange has switched to it or is in the process of doing so. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Elasticsearch is based on Lucene, though, which means it's not really an alternative but more of a wrapper/extension.