# What is the best Java text indexing library for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-indexing

To the moment I know that compass may handle this work. But indexing with compass looks pretty expensive. Is there any lighter alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is the de-facto choice for full text indexing in Java. Looks like [Compass Core](http://www.opensymphony.com/compass/content/about.html) contains "An implementation of Lucene Directory to store the index within a database (using Jdbc). It is separated from Compass code base and can be used with pure Lucene applications." plus tons of other stuff. You could try to separate just the Lucence component thereby stripping away several libs and making it more lightweight. Either that or ditch Compass altogether and use pure unadorned Lucene.

Comment: Yep, probably I will go this way. My concern about using Lucene is that IO is very costly on App Engine and I hope that some body already produced optimized version of Lucene or home grown library which takes extremly high IO cost in account.

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, I don't know if Lucene will be lighter than Compass in terms of indexing (why would it be, doesn't Compass use Lucene for that?).

Anyway, because you asked for alternatives, there is [GAELucene](http://code.google.com/p/gaelucene). I'm quoting [its announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/94dd53f6ce6644a9/4c0e36299159f2f6?show_docid=4c0e36299159f2f6) below:

> Enlightened by the discussion "[Can I
>   run Lucene in google app engine?](http://www.nabble.com/Can-I-run-Lucene-in-google-app-engine--td23017742.html)",
>   I implemented a google datastore based
>   Lucene component, GAELucene, which can
>   help you to run search applications on
>   google app engine.
>
> The main clazz of GAELucene include:
>
> - GAEDirectory - a read only Directory based on google datastore.
> - GAEFile - stands for an index file, the file's byte content will be
>     splited into multi GAEFileContent.
> - GAEFileContent - stands for a segment of index file.
> - GAECategory - the identifier of different indices.
> - GAEIndexInput - a memory-resident IndexInput? implementation like the
>     RAMInputStream.
> - GAEIndexReader - wrapper for IndexReader? that cached in
>     GAEIndexReaderPool
> - GAEIndexReaderPool - pool for GAEIndexReader
>
> The following code snippet
>   demonstrates the use of GAELucene do
>   searching:
>
> ```
> Query queryObject = parserQuery(request);
> GAEIndexReaderPool readerPool = GAEIndexReaderPool.getInstance();
> GAEIndexReader indexReader = readerPool.borrowReader(INDEX_CATEGORY_DEMO);
> IndexSearcher searcher = newIndexSearcher(indexReader);
> Hits hits = searcher.search(queryObject);
> readerPool.returnReader(indexReader);
> ```

I warmly recommend to read the whole discussion on nabble, very informative.

Just in case, regarding Compass, Shay Banon wrote a blog entry detailing how to use Compass in App Engine here: http://www.kimchy.org/searchable-google-appengine-with-compass/

Comment: Keep in mind that GAELucene doesn't allow you to build index in GAE. You should prepare index files somewhere and upload them to GAE.

Comment: There's also a note in Google Code saying "GAELucene is not fit to run with huge indices, it does better for small indices, around 100Mb. For large changing indices, you need to find other solutions".

Answer (score 1):

For Google App Engine, the only indexing library I've seen is [appengine-search](http://github.com/DocSavage/appengine-search), with a description of how to use it on [this page](http://www.billkatz.com/2009/6/Simple-Full-Text-Search-for-App-Engine).  I haven't tried it out though.

I've used [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) (which Compass is based on) and found it to work great with comparatively low expense.  The indexing is a task that you can schedule at times that work for your app.

Some alternatives indexing projects are mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602787/which-are-the-best-alternatives-to-lucene), including [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) and [minion](https://minion.dev.java.net/).  I haven't checked either of these out though, since Lucene did everything I needed it to very well.

Answer (score 0):

The Google App engine internal search seems better, and even havsupport synonyms:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Lucene on GAE you might also have a look at [LuGAEne](https://github.com/svenjacobs/lugaene). It's an implementation of Lucene's [Directory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html) for GAE.

Usage is actually pretty simple, just replace one of Lucene's standard directories with `GaeDirectory`

```
Directory directory = new GaeDirectory("MyIndex");
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43);
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, analyzer);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
...
```

[gaelucene](https://code.google.com/p/gaelucene/) seems to be in "maintenance mode" (no commit since Sep 2009) and [lucene-appengine](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/) does not (yet) work when you're using [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) version 4 in your application.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of LuGAEne.