# Couple o' quick questions on Apache Lucene

Tags: lucene, full-text-indexing

-- I don't want to start any religious wars, but a quick google search indicates that Apache Lucene is the preferred open source tool for indexing and searching.  Are there others?

-- What file format does Lucene use to store its index file(s)?

Thank is advance.
Doug

Comment: You should really only ask one question in a question -- that makes it easier for people to find the answer to a particular question later.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Which are the best alternatives to Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602787/which-are-the-best-alternatives-to-lucene) And as a lucene user I can say it has improved a lot performance wise the last couple of versions (NOT meaning it was slow before!)
2. it uses an proprietary format [see here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/fileformats.html)

Comment: Thanks... the previous discussions on stack overflow are very useful.

Comment: the discussion it's one year old already. If you look at any perf comparison from that time, be warned that lucene 3.0 is quite faster now...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look at [Sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29). 
I have an experience with Lucene.net and we have many problems with multithread indexing. Lucene stores index in files, and this files can be locked by anti-viruses software. 
Also you can not compare numbers in Lucene: it is impossible to filter products by size and price.