# search engine to search documents from a local database

Tags: search-engine, text-mining

I am looking for a search engine that finds documents from my local database on the basis of a search query. The process does not involve any web pages. They include only a set of text documents(pdf and doc files). 
   Please suggest a few efficient search engines for this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) first (it is built on top of Lucene). Comes with a nice web based admin tool also.

Comment: great. my requirement would just be to enter a query and obtain the best set of documents from a local database with a good accuracy.

Comment: Try Ambar http://ambar.rdseventeen.com/, it's very easy to use and have simple REST API

Answer (score 1):

Tools

1. [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)    : Powerful text search and dynamic clustering. Try the example docs present in it.
2. [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/)  : Popular clustering algos are already present in it
3. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)  : Full-featured text search engine library

In my opinion **Solr** will be the best option for Search purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Lucene /Lucene.Net, however alternatives can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602787/which-are-the-best-alternatives-to-lucene) and [here](http://ask.slashdot.org/story/07/10/01/1959239/best-way-to-build-a-searchable-document-index).

Comment: thanks. But i would like to know which of these is the most efficient? can you help me out with that ?

Comment: Without knowing your requirements it will be impossible to answer which is the most efficient / best as each solution has its specific pros and cons.

Comment: my database will have around 200 text documents (pdfs mostly). And my task involves using a reference document to generate many queries and then use these queries to search for the document that matches the most with the reference document. So i will be having quite a lot of queries and I am expecting atleast an average accuracy.