# Sphinx and CLucene like indexing/searching engine?

Tags: search, indexing, sphinx, full-text-indexing, clucene

Are there any other indexing/searching engine like sphinx and Clucene?

I would like to split my document into several parts and index each part individually for later look-up.

any lighter (scalable) engine?

Cheers

Comment: I found some other links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602787/which-are-the-best-alternatives-to-lucene
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120965/which-search-technology-to-use-with-asp-net